# Display means (or # observations) by two variables

Tags: r

I would like to show a statistic (for this example, it would be very helpful to know how to do means and # of observations), by two other variable, where one variable is on one side and another variable is on another side.

I don't know if there is a way for R to figure out how to make it so that the value labels, which would be in string for this example, are rearranged for "optimal" viewing in the resulting table, but that would be ideal. What I have in mind is where the string value labels might be really long, so that in a resulting table everything just gets squished. If there really isn't a smart way but instead just the judicious use of \n, that would be fine too.

An example below for where means could be applied, along `group` and `type`.

```
# Example data frame 
df <- data.frame(
  num <- c(0.225802, 0.384, 0.583, 0.868, 0.3859, 0.58582, 0.9485802, 0.085802),
  type <- c("This is a description of type 1", "This is a description of type 2", "This is a description of type 3", "This is a description of type 4", "This is a description of type 1", "This is a description of type 2", "This is a description of type 3", "This is a description of type 4"),
  group <- c("This is a really long description for group A", "This is a really long description for group A", "This is a really long description for group A", "This is a really long description for group A", "This is a really long description for group B", "This is a really long description for group B", "This is a really long description for group B", "This is a really long description for group B")
)
colnames(df) <- c("num", "type", "group")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would you want to recode `type` and `group` to just contain the Type and Group information in your aggregation table with the mean and #obs? As in, merely showing "Group A" and "Type 2" for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using data.table. In this case, I create a summary table containing the Means and No. Obs for `num` across `Type`/`Group` pairs.

**Code**

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)

untypes = df[, unique(as.character(type))] # Unique type descr
ungroups = df[, unique(as.character(group))] # Unique group descr

types = c(1,2,3,4) # Short types in the order they appear in `untypes` (1 to 4)
groups = c('A', 'B') # Short groups in the order they appear in `ungroups` (A to B)

df[, stype := sapply(type, function(x) types[which(untypes == x)])] # Assign short notation type ID
df[, sgroup := sapply(group, function(x) groups[which(ungroups == x)])] # Assign short notation group ID

dcast(df[, .(Mean = mean(num), No = length(num)), .(stype, sgroup)], stype ~ sgroup, value.var = c('Mean', 'No')) # Create summary matrix
```

**Result**

```
   stype   Mean_A    Mean_B No_A No_B
1:     1 0.225802 0.3859000    1    1
2:     2 0.384000 0.5858200    1    1
3:     3 0.583000 0.9485802    1    1
4:     4 0.868000 0.0858020    1    1
```

It is important that `types` and `groups` are declared such that their orders coincide with the corresponding orders of `untypes` and `ungroups`, respectively. For instance, if the long description of type 2 enters as the second observation in `untypes`, then `types[2]` must equal 2.